# Alpine: How to forcibly remove a package even if it would break dependencies?

Tags: alpine-linux

I'm trying to build a super-minimal Linux with Alpine. I don't need `linux-firmware` as it installs firmware for everything, using up 300+MB of space. This is a stock installation. However I can't uninstall any of the linux-firmware packages:

```
dev-alpine:~# apk del --force --force-broken-world linux-firmware
World updated, but the following packages are not removed due to:
  linux-firmware: linux-vanilla

OK: 504 MiB in 122 packages
```

More than half the stock install is the firmware!

Short of just deleting the files themselves (which will come back on an update!), how can I force Alpine to remove all the firmware files I don't need?

(Given that the firmware files already seem to be separated out, it seems that at some point it was considered that you would want to selectively install only firmware you need... but even that won't work:)

```
dev-alpine:~# apk del --force --force-broken-world linux-firmware-amdgpu
World updated, but the following packages are not removed due to:
  linux-firmware-amdgpu: linux-firmware linux-vanilla

OK: 504 MiB in 122 packages
```

Answer (score 5):

APK Tools [does not support forced package removal](https://git.alpinelinux.org/cgit/apk-tools/tree/src/del.c?id=e1a05c74cb8ae6ab41ee960343cc64a0a9af95a5#n125), because that would break the graph that it uses to represent packages.

To answer how to remove firmware: you may install [`linux-firmware-none`](https://git.alpinelinux.org/cgit/aports/tree/main/linux-firmware/APKBUILD?id=cfd515128ac1296a8c8365f4970588b01e004320#n126), which provides `linux-firmware-any` and satisfies the kernel package's dependency.  At that point, you should be able to remove `linux-firmware`.

Comment: As of v3.14 installing linux-firmware-none purges all other firmware packages.